# List of Powered off VMs with date of the event, beyond 30 days

Tags: vmware, vsphere, powercli

I am trying to write a script to get the **VM powered off date and time beyond 30 days** (all time since the Vsphere setup), I came to know they were only available if i parse the latest vmware.log of powered off vms and check the last string date in it.

I have with script that i have included below this script which just gives me the output for last 30 days

````
```
$VMs = get-vm | Where powerstate -eq "poweredoff"


Get-VIEvent -Entity $VMs -MaxSamples ([int]::MaxValue) |

where {$_ -is [VMware.Vim.VmPoweredOffEvent]} |

Group-Object -Property {$_.Vm.Name} | %{

  $lastPO = $_.Group | Sort-Object -Property CreatedTime -Descending | Select -First 1

  $vm = Get-VIObjectByVIView -MORef $_.Group[0].VM.VM

  $cloumn = '' | select VMName,Powerstate,PowerOFF

```
````

I expect results beyond 30 days with the help of vmware log files, currently i get results for 30 days

Comment: I had to do something similar, we had issue with VMWare logging crashing vcenter in large environments so our history is off on some environments or set to  7 days. To work round this I punt every event in to influx db (batched hourly) I then set influx db to auto purge data after 6months.  I can then achieve the above.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple potential causes. The first, you don't seem to be actually limiting the time to be 30 days or older. You're grabbing all of the events as a whole. The second, the vCenter logs roll up at certain intervals which turns them into zip files that the `Get-VIEvent` cmdlet will not be able to read anymore. This is where a log parser comes into play, something like Log Insight or Splunk/SolarWinds/Nagios.